# Read/write register in another cpu core

Tags: x86, arm, cpu

Is it possible for one cpu core to read/write to/from a register in another cpu core?

If not directly possible by assembly instructions, is this something a cpu would do internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is for ARM, but should apply for x86 as well.

No, it's not possible to write an internal register of one core from an other core, because this would require buses and synchronization between the cores. This would deeply decrease the performances, as usually two cores aren't even synchronous.

The nearest mechanism to share data between cores is usually a fast migration of L1 cache lines between cores via the snoop control unit (for cores that share the same L2 cache), or by a cache-coherent interconnect (between clusters linked in big.LITTLE systems).

As you did not clearly indicate which register you want to access, I must notice that, in current microprocessors, many registers are not in the cores. I mentioned the snoop control unit, that is a component you'll find in every multi-core ARM processors, that has registers, but that doesn't belong to any core, and its registers may be accessed by any core of the processor.